# Update repository version for Vagrant

Tags: 18.04, vagrant

I wanted to install latest Vagrant, so followed the steps as below :

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

Some other repo link has broken and i dont want to update it. As suggested online i have `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` run, didnt help much. How can i skip this error and just continue with the next update ?

```
 sudo apt-get install vagrant
```

However i have run the above command and this installed 2.0.2 version of vagrant where as the latest one is 2.2.9, how can i update the repository URL to update version so that i get the latest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> where as the latest one is 2.2.9

Not for 18.04 as that one has [2.0.6](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=vagrant). Even [Groovy](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=vagrant) (=20.10) does not have 2.2.9 but will get 2.27.

If you want the latest use their [own download](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html) and install that. From command line you can also do (adjust VER to the latest version; now 2.2.9):

```
VER="2.2.9"
wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/${VER}/vagrant_${VER}_x86_64.deb
sudo dpkg -i vagrant_${VER}_x86_64.deb
sudo apt -f install
```

The last command is not needed if there are no missing dependencies.

---

There is also on [unofficial debian repository](https://vagrant-deb.linestarve.com/):

```
sudo bash -c 'echo deb https://vagrant-deb.linestarve.com/ any main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wolfgang42-vagrant.list'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-key AD319E0F7CFFA38B4D9F6E55CE3F3DE92099F7A4D2BABDFD63EA9ECAB4E09C7228A873EA3C7C705F
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install vagrant
```

Mind that you need to trust the owner to not mess with the source.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have tried the first suggested way, when i see `vagrant -v` i dont see it as installed. I get command not found. Secondly i did not want to try unofficial stuff. So i there a way to make the deb installation as visible to my env but setting some path ?

Comment: That last comment ... then you need to stick with 2.0.6. That is the ONLY official version for 18.04. And the unofficial repo is listed last for a reason. The 1st option should be the one to use: it is from the creators of vagrant.

Comment: Anyway even the above didnt work gpg: "AD319E0F7CFFA38B4D9F6E55CE3F3DE92099F7A4D2BABDFD63EA9ECAB4E09C7228A873EA3C7C705F" not a key ID: skipping